# Sandbox overflow

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Your task is to output a square sandbox of size `n+2` with `/` characters in the corners and `|` for the sides, and `-` for the top, with `n**2` layers of sand (`.`) overflowing out of the sandbox of width `n+2`

## Testcases

```
1
->
/-/
|.|
/./
...

2
->
/--/
|..|
|..|
/../
....
....
....
....

3
->
/---/
|...|
|...|
|...|
/.../
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

Trailing spaces and newlines are allowed

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: Why are there 10 layers of sand at the bottom for `n=3`?

Comment: Trailing newline is allowed, right? (you allow trailing spaces; not sure about trailing newline)

Comment: @ophact Trailing whitespace is allowed by default for [tag:ascii-art] challenges, so if the question doesn't specify it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｎθ↶ＵＢ.×.×θθ/Ｆ³«θ↶²/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orILMsv8QnNa1EA8gJTi1xSkzOTi/KL81L0VDSUwIpKMrMK9EIycxNLQaJ6ChAmIU6CoWamnB5JX2Q2rT8IgUNY02Fai5OiDDIBk6EFUZgLpKG2v//jf/rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
↶
```

Change the default drawing direction to up. (I do it here because I can use the default pivot of 90°.)

```
ＵＢ.
```

Set the default character for unpainted areas to `.`.

```
×.×θθ
```

Draw the right-hand edge of the overflowing sand. (The rest of the sand gets drawn as part of the unpainted area.)

```
/
```

Draw the bottom right `/`.

```
Ｆ³«
```

Repeat three times.

```
θ
```

Draw the right `|`s, the top `-`s or the left `|`s as appropriate.

```
↶²
```

Pivot the default drawing direction by another 90°.

```
/
```

Draw the top right, top left or bottom right `/` as appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

```python
n=input()
i=2
while~n*n<i:i-=1;d='/.|'[~-i*(i+n)and~(i<-n)];print d+'-.'[i<1]*n+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHdCkAwAAbQe0/hbn@NcMf2JHKhpnylz9Ikpb36nBPftJ/sS6EH452kquD76tlxbJmaDiOs76bgRdt8Ys4WWsJQrQxZwlmqZYoXmOpghG3EDNctmiaUMvw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 69 bytes

```
lambda n:[f"/{'-'*n}/",*n*[f"|{(c:='.'*n)}|"],f"/{c}/",*n*n*[c+'..']]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3XXMSc5NSEhXyrKLTlPSr1XXVtfJq9ZV0tPK0gAI11RrJVrbqekBBzdoapVgdkJpkqDxQRbK2up6eemws1DCdtPwihTyFzDyFosS89FQNQx0TTauCosy8Eg2tNI08TR0lJZ3i1AJbpZg8JU2IngULIDQA)

-2 bytes thanks to @ophact.

Outputs a list of lines, as [allowed by standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095).

Comment: You can save 2 bytes as follows: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3XXMSc5NSEhXyrKLTlPSr1XXVtfJq9ZV0tPK0gAI11RrJVrbqekBBzdoapVgdkJpkqDxQRbK2up6eemws1DCdtPwihTyFzDyFosS89FQNQx0TTauCosy8Eg2tNI08TR0lJZ3i1AJbpZg8JU2IngULIDQA

Comment: Idk if this output format is allowed, but [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3XXISc5NSEhXyrKLTlPSr1XXVtfJq9ZV08rTSlGqqNZKtbNX1gEKatTUxeUraICXJIGmtPCCMTtZW19NTj42FmqWTll-kkKeQmadQlJiXnqphqGOiaVVQlJlXoqGVppGnqaOkpFOcWmCrBDRKE6JnwQIIDQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>30</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'-×'/.ø©Ð„|.‡I.D®W'.:ÐW‡In.D»
```

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E because it can take the minimum character of a string (based on its unicode value), saving 2 bytes over repushing the characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fXffwdHV9vcM7Dq08POFRw7wavUcNCz31XA6tC1fXszo8IRzEzQPyd///bwQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W/iruSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4en4/VfXPTxdXV/v8I5DKw9PeNQwr0bvUcNCPz2XQ@vC1fWsDk8IB3HzgPzd/3UObbP/bwQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'-×      '# Repeat "-" the (implicit) input amount of times as string
   '/.ø  '# Surround it with leading/trailing "/"
       ©  # Store this string in variable `®` (without popping)
Ð         # Triplicate it
 „|.‡     # Transliterate the "/" to "|" and "-" to "." in the other copy (the
          # transliterate ignores the trailing "…---/" since the strings are
          # of unequal length)
     I.D  # Duplicate it the input amount of times
®         # Push string `®`
 W        # Push the minimum (without popping): "-"
  '.:    '# Replace all "-" with "." in string `®`
Ð         # Triplicate it
 W        # Push the minimum (without popping): "."
  ‡       # Replace all "/" with "." (transliterate again ignores the trailing
          # "…---/")
   In     # Push the input, and square it
     .D   # Duplicate this string of "."s that many times
»         # Join all strings on the stack by newlines
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```
=LET(r,REPT(".",A1),"/"&REPT("-",A1)&"/"&REPT("
|"&r&"|",A1)&"
/"&r&"/
"&REPT("."&r&".
",A1^2))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

## Java 11, 121 bytes

```java
n->"/"+"-".repeat(n)+"/\n"+("|"+".".repeat(n)+"|\n").repeat(n)+"/"+".".repeat(n)+"/\n"+(".".repeat(n+2)+"\n").repeat(n*n)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZCxTsNAEET7fMVqqztOvgjoMKanIBSUIcXhXNAGZ23Z60go8bc7G9sFFoLmpJt5I83sPhxDst9@9XkRmgZeAvFpAUAssd6FPMLq@gV4k5r4E3KjDrBNVewW@jQShHJYAUPWc/KES3SYoK9jFYMYtg6X74zO4FkNPzPOatgZ@QuZsj9Ed6fyLHjDtk@vXar2o9AuU6VjSVs46B4zdl9vgh237Mp6mEHZbUqP2X1Kzk2WDv1uJB582YqvNCYFG3zmqpUHQEfD8L@w11ZG7j@Kvd7QTkQ3nLHrLw)

Straight-forward approach using Java 11+'s [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)).

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 58 bytes

Prompts for n

```
o,(⍉(n,⍴c)⍴c←'-',((n+1)+n*2)⍴'.'),o←(1,n,1,(n←⎕)*2)/'/|/.'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tf76OxqPeTo08nUe9W5I1QQRQTl1XXUdDI0/bUFM7T8sIJKqup66pkw@U0jDUydMx1NHIA7KBRmkCpfXV9Wv09dT/A83j@p/GZcilrqDOlcZlBKWNuQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 42 bytes

```
.+
/$&*-/¶$&*$(|$&*.|¶)/$&*./$&**$(¶.$&*..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS19FTUtX/9A2IKWiUQMk9WoObdMEieqBCKDgoW16IJ7e//@GXEZcxgA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Straightforward application of Retina 1's string repeat operator, except that `**` is shorthand for `*$&*` thus squaring the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 77 bytes

```javascript
n=>`/${(C=D=>D.repeat(n))('-')}/
${C(`|${a=C('.')}|
`)}/${a}/
`+C(C(a+`..
`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxCoQwDADQ3e8oNEWMw81xiR@S4NXjRFpRcal@e8363qKXHtP@384u5W@sM9VEg/SuANNIw4h73KKekEIA3/nw9I0rDHK7osTg0ehuxNzAUloGBm0F0TTUKacjrxHX/IMZPiYv)

Constructs a large template string using a function `C` to shorten the usage of `repeat`.

Thanks @Arnauld for -4 bytes by reminding me that literal linefeeds exist. (I've been doing way too much Python recently.)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcmxCoQwDADQ3e8oNEWMw81xiR@S4NXjRFpRcal@e8363qKXHtP@384u5W@sM9VEg/SuANNIw4h73KKekEIA3/nw9I0rDHK7osTg0ehuxNzAUloGBm0F0TTUKacjrxHX/IMZPiYv) with literal line feeds.

Comment: @Arnauld Wow, I've been doing too much Python so I forgot about literal line-feeds...

Answer (score 1):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>143</s> 137 bytes

*saved 6 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat*

```C
j;main(n){scanf("%d",&n);char s[n+=2];for(;j<n;puts(s))memset(s,46-!j,n),*s=s[n-1]="/|"[j++&&j^n];*s=s[--n]=46;for(j=--n*n;j--;)puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEAC/ogFD0mYRS@llzUtKhBBbdSFb6daT@vZYisdhhklwS6kUwhwfbNi@JUUejTpcldNsMd3jvJOea98EHKfZIJ0Zn69FjFibhyzDYsS1HezJsXWV@LWGU/Dq@FE91bXWdOGAmwDg4NtuG5FfqWIkALT/IX5LaX4)

Indented version:

```
j;
main(n){
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char s[n+=2];
    for(;j<n;puts(s))
        memset(s,46-!j,n),
        *s=s[n-1]="/|"[j++&&j^n];
    *s=s[--n]=46;for(j=--n*n;j--;)puts(s);
}
```

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEAC/ogFDtkkQg3hZ85ISIcRWXcgq3XpS3x6LeByYmeIvpbRGWPONDcNLSubRqM1ZOc2A5ZqnlfRsY0g43ieDdagyzEbc/uDX5BgcHRkfz1mMAHQSF9vvUlTbt@rJWq3pxAnJx/AbUBdpIY/wb/DTWvgC "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>140</s> 134 bytes

```rust
|i|{let r=".".repeat(i);print!("/{}/
{}/{}/
{}
","-".repeat(i),format!("|{}|
",r).repeat(i),r,(".".repeat(i+2)+"
").repeat(i.pow(2)))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDoMwDEX3nCL1ZAsIKt2K6FUqhkSKVAIyQUhNcvYU2qEZ/P7wnszb6rNxchqtQ5JBvLSX5m4cbqt9a5LN4ykHmaON4VQ8gALFetGjR0v9wtb5C0IbUiuO@42AGpoiq83M03h2MaR4WKZCco3l06qjCgT8C7XMO3ZElHIvDF7pZPfl7WDKHw)

**To 134 bytes:** I was able to save 6 bytes by using type hinting.

The link includes a header and a footer for calling the closure, and I call it for `1`, `2`, and `3`, to prove that it works!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `J`, 32 bytes

```
¤-\/pǏD£‛/-‛|.Ŀ⁰Ḋ¥:g\.VDg\/$V⁰²Ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJKIiwiIiwiwqQtXFwvcMePRMKj4oCbLy3igJt8LsS/4oGw4biKwqU6Z1xcLlZEZ1xcLyRW4oGwwrLhuIoiLCIiLCIzIl0=)

### How?

```
¤-\/pǏD£‛/-‛|.Ŀ⁰Ḋ¥:g\.VDg\/$V⁰²Ḋ
¤                                # Push an empty string
 -                               # Push "-" * a + b (where a is the (implicit) input, and b is the empty string)
  \/p                            # Prepend "/"
     Ǐ                           # Append its first character (the slash)
      D                          # Triplicate
       £                         # Pop and store in the register
        ‛/-                      # Push string "/-"
           ‛|.                   # Push string "|." (for input 3, stack e.g. ["/---/", "/---/", "/-", "|."])
              Ŀ                  # Transliterate (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|"])
               ⁰Ḋ                # Duplicate the top value of the stack the input amount of times (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|"])
                 ¥               # Push contents of register (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/---/"])
                  :              # Duplicate (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/---/", "/---/"])
                   g             # Take the minimum by character code, which is "-" (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/---/", "-"])
                    \.V          # Replace with a period (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/.../"])
                       D         # Triplicate (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/.../", "/.../", "/.../"])
                        g        # Take the minimum by character code, which is "." (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/.../", "/.../", "."])
                         \/      # Push "/"
                           $     # Swap with the period (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/.../", "/.../", "/", "."])
                            V    # Replace (stack e.g. ["/---/", "|...|", "|...|", "|...|", "/.../", "....."])
                             ⁰²  # Push the input squared
                               Ḋ # Duplicate the top value of the stack that many times
                                 # J flag joins the stack by newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 37 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
'.*'|▌'|+k(Ä_'-k*'/▌'/+_¬'.k⌠*k²(Ä_]n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/19dT0u95tG0HvUa7WyNwy3x6rrZWur6IAF97fhDa9T1sh/1LNDKPrQJJBmb9z/vvyGXEZcxlwkA)

**Explanation:**

```python
'.*    '# Push a string with the (implicit) input amount of "."
'|▌    '# Prepend "|"
'|+    '# Append "|"
k(Ä     # Loop the input-1 amount of times,
        # using a single character as inner code-block:
   _    #  Duplicate the "|...|" string
'-k*   '# Push a string with the input amount of "-"
'/▌'/+  # Surround it with leading "/"
_       # Duplicate it
 ¬      # Rotate the items on the entire stack once
'.k⌠*  '# Push a string with the input+2 amount of "."
k²(Ä    # Loop input²-1 amount of times,
        #  using a single character as inner code-block:
    _   #  Duplicate the "." string
]       # Wrap the stack into a list
 n      # Join this list with newline delimiter
        # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, 66 bytes

```perl
$;=c x$_;$_=a."-"x$_.ad."b$;bd"x$_.a.$;.a."dcc$;"x$_**2;y;a-d;/|..
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJDs9YyB4JF87JF89YS5cIi1cIngkXy5hZC5cImIkO2JkXCJ4JF8uYS4kOy5hLlwiZGNjJDtcIngkXyoqMjt5O2EtZDsvfC5cbiIsImFyZ3MiOiItcGwiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjMifQ==)

### Explanation

Generates the output, char by char, replacing characters used multiple times with bareword letters to avoid additional quotes or brackets. Makes use of operator precedence in that `x**y` works without quotes, but `x*x` doesn't. Also makes use of the fact that `-p` adds `;}` to the code and uses `;` as the separator for `y///`, saving another byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 38 bytes

```
QQttGU+&O46+47blht&(45G:Q(!'|'5MlOh&(c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzCwpMQ9VFvN38RM28Q8KSejRE3DxNTdKlBDUb1G3dQ3xz9DTSP5/39jAA)